# How to Include Property

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following example:

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    var query = from entityA in context.EntityA.Include("TestProperty")
                join entityB in context.EntityB on entityA.Id equals entityB.EntityAId
                join entityC in context.EntityC on entityB.Id equals entityC.EntityBId
                where entityC.Id == id
                select entityA;

    List<EntityA> toReturn = query.ToList();

    return toReturn;
}
```

My joins are all working as expected, however, my 'TestProperty' navigation property is not loaded properly. I look, during runtime, and it is null.

When I do the following:

```
context.LoadProperty(toReturn, "TestProperty");
```

It loads the 'TestProperty' property correctly. Is there something I am doing incorrectly in my LINQ-to-SQL statement?

UPDATE:
I changed the first line to be:

```
from entityA in context.EntityA.Include("TestProperty").ToList()
```

And left the rest of the lines below that the same and it loaded my property correctly. Is this the proper solution to the problem?

Comment: This looks like a Linq to Entities question, not Linq-to-SQL. You'll probably have more luck if you edit and re-tag your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

"Is this the proper solution to the problem?" it is the worst possible solution, because your are now doing the whole query client-side.

Answer (score -1):

Include must be written after join & where clause

Check this:

```
var query = ((from entityA in context.EntityA
                join entityB in context.EntityB on entityA.Id equals entityB.EntityAId
                join entityC in context.EntityC on entityB.Id equals entityC.EntityBId
                where entityC.Id == id
                select entityA) as objectQuery<EntityA>).Include("TestProperty")
```